# Major styling issue with view in IE8/9: Looks fine in Chrome/FF. RoR 3.0 E Commerce App

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-9

So yeah, me being a n00b I didn't test in IE8 or 9. I work on a Mac. Buddy just pulled it up in IE9 and looks wayyyyy off. Haven't seen it in ie8 but can't imagine it looks any better. Just installed VirtualBox but what is the most efficient/acceptable/legal way to go about this situation?

Any advice is greatly appreciated. Not sure what the hell to do as this is my first semi-large app.

Comment: LOL, why hello Apnea. Yeaaaa this isn't too fun. Trying this for now, going to take a while to download but will let you know how it turns out. curl -s https://raw.github.com/xdissent/ievms/master/ievms.sh | bash

Answer (score 2):

Not sure about the legal stuff, but this is probably the easiest way to get IE up and running with VirtualBox on OS X: http://osxdaily.com/2011/09/04/internet-explorer-for-mac-ie7-ie8-ie-9-free/

Comment: Yep yep this is what I'm downloading now :) Cheers, will let you know how it turns out.

Comment: Yeah, it takes forever to download, but let me know how it works out for you.